# Cross term in the spacetime metric of a spatially homogeneous and isotrpoic Universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor

Consider the metric $ds^2=c^2dt^2+g_{0i}dt dx^i-g_{ij}dx^i dx^j$. How can I argue that the second term violates spatial homegenity or isotropy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the transformation $x \to -x$, apply it to get

$$ds^2=c^2dt^2-g_{0i}dt dx^i-g_{ij}dx^i dx^j$$

This differs from the original metric.

Answer (score 0):

In the book "*Theoretical Astrophysics: Volume 3* by *Thanu Padmanabhan*" it is argued (below Eq. [3.1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-yvq5BEsFvcC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=otherwise%20they%20identify%20a%20particular%20direction%20in%20space%20related%20to%20the%20three%20vector&source=bl&ots=pETIskAcaL&sig=0ttKjDwNOgP5IKF0dcm20k_ZJNE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGqt-x5ZnaAhVBro8KHUkXDkgQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=otherwise%20they%20identify%20a%20particular%20direction%20in%20space%20related%20to%20the%20three%20vector&f=false)) that the isotropy of space implies that $g_{0i}$'s must vanish otherwise at each point in space there is a preferred direction related to a 3-vector $v_i=g_{0i}$ that violates isotropy.